# How to call define() with SQL statement with input parameters

Tags: php, mysql

Hey how do i call php define() with sql statement that has input parameters to another php page.

```
      define("GET_LAST_DATE", "
         SELECT o.`order_date`
         FROM autoship_order a, orders o
         WHERE a.last_order_id = o.order_id
     AND a.autoship_order = ?
             ");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to have the definition reference across other pages you will need to do `include_once` the definition file.

```
include_once "definition.php";
```

to use the `CONSTANT` in a mysqli query perform the following action.

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare(GET_LAST_DATE);
$stmt->bind_param("i", 1);
```

Comment: How do I call and assign a value to input parameter a.autoship_order=1  to GET_LAST_DATE define.

Comment: other.php look like this PDO

Comment: $stmt->bind_param("i", 1); the "i"?

Comment: i stands for integer. if you use a string use `s`